# wagtail def get_context and def serve

Tags: wagtail

I can add to the `context` in the `serve` method for a page, and get the context variable in the page template. I cannot seem to add to the context in `get_context`; or, access it in the page template. This is stumping me.

I'd like to add a variable or two to the context using the get_context function, and access that in the page template.

```
# If request.user is authenticated AND is registered for this event
# set that in the context
# ###---THIS DOES SEEM TO ADD TO CONTEXT, OR
# ###---IF IT DOES, THEN CANNOT ACCESS IT IN THE TEMPLATE--###
# def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
#     # pdb.set_trace()
#     context = super(EventPage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
#     if request.user.is_authenticated:
#         # pdb.set_trace()
#         for attendee in self.event.eventattendee_set.all():
#             if attendee.email == request.user.email:
#                 # user is an attendee for this event
#                 context["is_attendee"] = True
#                 break
#     context["hello"] = "hello"
#     return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accessing the added context data via `get_context` using the `page` or `self` prefix in the template. That would not have worked--at least it seems not to have. Access the context variables directly, without the prefix, and there you have it. Sometimes, one just has to step away from the keyboard. All is good with `get_context`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the full page model definition, so I assume it is for `EventPage`.  Also, the code you have above is commented out.  Is it commented out in your file?  That would explain why you're not getting anything.  Also, you don't have to do `super(EventPage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)`.  You can just do `super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)` (though what you have should work also).  Everything else looks correct.

Comment: Its commented out because I am using the serve method instead. Yes, this is an instance of the EventPage, hence that argument in the call to Super, along with its instance, self.